# Connecting Twilio API to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I am trying to deploy a python script in Google Cloud Functions where the user submits a yes-or-no answer from Whatsapp and it reaches the Twilio API. If this function receives a 'Yes' it activates a query in Google Big Query table and reply with a report. My point is: if I create this function with no authentication, it works fine. However, it doesn't work for me, because it gives private information about my company.

So, in order to avoid problems, I create a function authenticating with Cloud IAM. When I pass the service account to this function, I give permission to invoke cloud function, the account inherit all permissions to read and execute jobs in Big Query and I give permission to service agents. Even following all these steps, I'm still receiving a 403 error.

Here is the code I'm trying to deploy in Google Cloud Functions:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from sales import Sales
from flask import Flask, request
from functools import wraps
from utils import format_currency, emoji_alerts

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

def message_sales():
    data = (datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    resultado = Sales()

    return f""" message """ 
#here is where the message is generated, this f-string queries results in bigquery

@app.route('/reply', methods=['GET','POST'])
def send_message(request):  
    from twilio.rest import Client
    from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
    
    account_sid = os.getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
    auth_token = os.getenv('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    report = message_sales()

    if 'yes' in incoming_msg:
        msg.body(report)
        responded = True

    elif 'no' in incoming_msg:
        msg.body('Ok')
        responded = True

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=2020)
```

And here is the connection function to big query and a example of a query:

```
    def run_google_query(query):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
        client = bigquery.Client(project='project-id', credentials=credentials)
        return [row[0] for row in client.query(query)][0]

    def get_resultado_dia(self):
        return f"""
SELECT RESULTADO_ATUAL FROM `table` 
WHERE DATA_VENDA = '{self.ontem.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}'
"""
```

This is my last deploy. I have tried to use Secret Manager library, I have created a service account with the necessary permissions, I've given more permission to actual service accounts and nothing worked.

I believe that I need to authenticate the Twilio API with Google Cloud, but I can't find a clear explanation on how to procedure with that. Anyway, create a unauthenticated http request won't be an option, since the information shouldn't be open.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling to find an answer, I was able to figure out how to overcome this problem above.

I used a library to access the secret in Google Cloud called google-cloud-secret-manager. Then I defined a function to call it, as below.

```
def get_auth(project_id, secret_id, version_id):
    from google.cloud import secretmanager

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})

    payload = response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8').split(',')
    
    return payload
```

Other thing I need to do was to remove the credentials from my sales function, because my service account was able to access it automatically.

Finally, I created a new service account which invoke Cloud Functions, access secret manager and run jobs in Big Query.